# $f(x) \in R[X]$ irreducible $\Rightarrow (f(x))$ ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $R$ is a field, and $f(x) \in R[X]$ is an irreducible polynomial in $R[X]$, does then follow that $(f(x))$ is a (principal) ideal in $R[X]$?

[Edit]

My understanding (which may be wrong) of (f(x)) is the subset that is generated by taking all (finite) linear combinations of f(x), and I want to know if this is an ideal of $R[X]$.

Comment: Just to make sure: Do you mean by $(f)$ the ideal generated by $f$?

Comment: @JohannesKloos yes

Comment: So you’re asking if the ideal generated by $f$ is (A) an ideal that is (B) generated by one element?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense!

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I tried to clarified what I wanted to know

Comment: @k.stm please see my edit

Comment: Do you know what's a linear combination of one element?@muffel

Comment: Some patience is due here, imo. The OP is obviously confused by the definition of ideal, principal ideal and etc. In *any* (commutative) ring $\;R\;$ and for *any* element $\;r\in R\;$ , the set $\;\langle r\rangle:=\{xr\;:\;x\in R\}\;$ is an ideal called *the principal* ideal generated by $\;r\;$ . Thus, in this question, $\;\langle f(x)\rangle\;$ is **always** a principal ideal, no matter what $\;f(x)\;$ is. It can be proved though that $\;f(x)\;$ is a *prime* of the ring $\;R[x]\;,\;\;R\;$ a field iff it is irreducible iff $\;I=\langle f(x)\rangle\;$ is a prime ideal iff it is maximal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, take any arbitrary ring $S$, a family of elements element $F ⊂ S$ and examine the set of finite linear combinations of elements of $F$ in $S$
$$S_F = \{Σ_{f ∈ F'}^n a_f f;~\text{$F' ⊂ F$ is finite and for all $f ∈ F'$, $a_f ∈ S$}\}.$$
Prove that:

1. $S_F = \bigcap \{I ⊂ S;~\text{$I$ is an ideal of $S$ with $F ⊂ I$}\}$.
2. Arbitrary intersections of ideals are ideals.

The right set in (1.) should be taken as the definition of the *ideal generated by $F$*. And to be clear, it is the intersection of all ideals in $S$ containing $F$. By (2.) $S_F$ is an ideal.

Your claim follows for $F = \{f\}$.

> Edit: Actually, for your case just prove that $S_{\{f\}} = \{af;~a ∈ S\}$.

So this has nothing to with $R$ being a field or $f$ being irreducible.

Answer (score 1):

Your question boils down to basic logic.

Given any element of a ring we can consider the ideal generated by it. Irreducibility is irrelevant.

So your question is the following: If I consider the ideal generated by (the one polynomial) $f(x)\in R[x]$ then is it generated by one element?

The answer is yes by the reflexive property of equality...